# What HTML5 video event refers to the currentTime of the video being played?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, media-player

I want the user to have the option to `skip` the `preroll ad` after a specified time (say 5 secs into the ad). Then the normal video would play. How can I achieve this? Currently I have something inline of this:

```
var adManager = function () {
    var adSrc = url,
        src = "http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4";
    var adEnded = function () {
        videoPlayer.removeEventListener("ended", adEnded, false);
        videoPlayer.removeEventListener("playing", adPlaying, false);
        $("#companionad").hide();
        videoPlayer.src = src;
        videoPlayer.load();
        videoPlayer.play();
        console.log(videoPlayer.currentTime);
    };
    var adPlaying = function () {
        var companionad = $(responseXML).find("HTMLResource").text();
        $("#companionad").html(companionad);
        console.log(videoPlayer.currentTime);
    }
    return {
        init: function () {
            videoPlayer.src = adSrc;
            videoPlayer.load();
            videoPlayer.addEventListener("ended", adEnded, false);
            videoPlayer.addEventListener("playing", adPlaying, false);
            if (videoPlayer.currentTime > 5) {
                $("#skip").show();
            }
            console.log(videoPlayer.currentTime);
        }
    };
}();
adManager.init();
```

What I am trying to do is:

```
if (videoPlayer.currentTime > 5) {
    $("#skip").show();
}
```

show the `skip` button and continue to normal video. Is there any `event` that is continually fired as the video play progresses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do your check against the `media.currentTime` property in a handler for the `timeupdate` event. See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/timeupdate):

> The timeupdate event is fired when the time indicated by the
>   currentTime attribute has been updated.

Just as an aside, this [HTML5 video demo page](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) is a really handy reference for playing around with the various properties and events available to you.